# React Native , Unable to update component periodically

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native just started learning.
here is what i have tried

```
 export default class HomeComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  item: [],
 };
 mixins: [TimerMixin];

 }
 componentDidMount(){

this.interval = setInterval(() => {
console.log('hi');
  this.setState({item: updateValue})
 }, 6000); //6 seconds
 }

 render() {
return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#101010' }}>

</View>;
 }
```

Its working fine , but i am just thinking about the warning, should i just ignore it ? or is there  better way of doing it!.

[image: i am getting this warning]
[image: timer log]

Comment: above this warning the "hi" is logged?

Comment: yes  ! timer is working fine ,here is the log  '02-11 12:01:54.899 28092 32002 I ReactNativeJS: hi' @ messerbill

Comment: and the warning disappears if you remove the `setIntervall()` method?

Comment: yes warning disappears after removing setIntervall() method , i even tried to create separate method but whenever i try to call it gives me the same warning. @messerbill

Comment: so to get it clear: the warning appears only for one single time while the `hi` is logged every 6 seconds?

Comment: only one time , with first hi @ messerbill

Comment: does using `componentWillMount()` instead of `componentDidMount()` make a difference?

Comment: i have tried both componentWillMount(), componentDidMount() giving me the same warning . @messerbill

Comment: so can you set up a fiddle or codepen or smth like this?

Comment: i don't know how to use fiddle or codepen for react native , as far as i know react native requires android sdk and react native packages  etc in order to run react native codes . @ messerbill

Comment: you can include react into those playgrounds...also here in the internal stackoverflow "playground"

Comment: i am quite new to react too, imo this should work but if not i need to play around a bit...thats why i need this code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function continues to update even after the component unmount causing the error. You should use the componentWillUnmount() function of the React lifecycle and clear the "setInterval" function from running when the component is no longer mounted.

You can use:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

to turn off the update once the component unmount.